# Can "by" and "from" be used interchangeably at times?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

"He gets all his knowledge about politics from watching the television."

I saw this sentence in a dictionary, and I want to know whether "by" can be used in place of "from" in that sentence. No matter how much I read about prepositions, especially "from", "in", and "by", I never learn to use them perfectly.

"I gained a detailed knowledge of biology by watching documentaries about plants and animals."
Source: me; this one is my sentence.

Is it correct to use "by" in this case?

"Children learn how to do jobs they may find themselves in in the future from doing unpaid work."
Source: me

Is it grammatical to use "from" in this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either "by" or "from". There are no rules or differences in meaning.

Typically, however, you would say:

> from/by watching <strike>the</strike> television

Comment: "From" works because watching television is a source of knowledge. "By" works because watching television is a way of achieving a goal (obtaining knowledge).